# using jdbc to query two databases to the same instance of sql server

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

In a Java standalone client server application (using Netbeans)  I use a static method to connect to SQL server : but if I use the second connection I am getting the error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Utili.StaticConnessione.getConnessione2()Ljava/sql/Connection;
```

Can someone help me?
thanks

```
   public class StaticConnessione {
 // first coonection
public static Connection getConnessione1() throws SQLException {

    String s = System.getProperty("user.name");
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=FIRST_DB;user=sa; password = abc");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "msg", 2);
    }
    return null;
}
// second connection

public static Connection getConnessione2() throws SQLException {
    // first coonection
    String s = System.getProperty("user.name");
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=SECOND_DB;user=sa;password = abc");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "msg", 2);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried clean/recompiling your code? Looks like JVM is not able to find getConnessione2() method

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code where you are calling getConnessione1 and getConnessione2 ? Also, you should probably look at using a connection pool to access your database.

Comment: Something like this should be written as a comment to the question as it is not an answer

Comment: @TI I don't see the option to add any comments to the OPs question. Probably because my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: the code is calling by jasper report engine. i wilpost the code as soon as possible. what is a connection pool?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool . Usually provided by the application server.

Comment: connection pool is not for me but only for web app.Now i try to not use static metod maybe it will go well

Comment: @user2023281 not necessarily. There are stand alone tools as well. For e.g. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: thanks for the answers but I solved the problem using non static method for get connections.